# .NET application: security issue hosting media files on an a seperate IIS site

Tags: c#, iis-7

I am maintaining a .NET (C#) web application which allows users to login, answer questionnaires and whatnot.  We are hosting the site under IIS 7.  Upon login users have access to media files such as pdf, mp3 and mp4 (video).  Assume for heresay that our site is http://www.webapplication.com

We have recently modified our web application to cater for mobile devices.  In doing this however, it was noted that video's (mp4's) would not display on mobile devices when being accessed by a hard path in the web application, such as C:\webapplication\mediafiles\myfilenampe.mp4.  Video files would only display if we accessed them in a site such as media.webapplication.com.  So we did the following:

1)  Created a separate file server in IIS calling it (consistent with the above example) media.webapplication.com.  This site has no applications running, it just contains the media files.

2)  Accessed the media from our web application (www.webapplication.com) with embedded links that point to the files in media.webapplication.com.  The following would be an example of a file being pointed to by our webapp:  http://media.webapplication.com:1313/video/qabzxujzyrzcspcmskjuadpkg.mp4

There is however a security issue with our implementation.  If a person has the exact link to the media site and any given file such as the example in #2 above, they can access the file anywhere on the internet (in any browser), without being logged into www.webapplication.com.

So the question is, what would be the best method of restricting access to the files in media.webapplication.com making them only accessible to people using our webapp under www.webapplication.com?  Is this even possible or should I look for a way to host the media files in the same site as our webapp?

Answer (score 0):

The permission settings on the folder is what you want to set. Add the app pool user so that you have full control and manage the permission to upload in your application.